# IE 9 is not rendering images with Raphael JS library

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, raphael

I am making a Raphael JS animation, and for some reason, I cannot get images to render in internet explorer 9. here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/raphael-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var layer0 = Raphael("layer0", 980, 650);
        var bg = layer0.image("images/landscape_background.jpg", 0, 0, aniWidth, aniHeight);
    });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="layer" id="layer0">
    </div>
    <div class="layer" id="layer1">
    </div>
    <div class="layer" id="layer2">
    </div>
    <div class="layer" id="layer3">
    </div>
    <div class="layer" id="layer4">
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

It works fine in chrome and firefox, just not ie 9.

Comment: try putting the browser into IE8 compatibility mode. If that works, than its an issue with IE9. Otherwise, its your code

Comment: Yeah i've tried that but can't see what's wrong with my code. Can anyone else see what i've done wrong?

Comment: try running the Raphael code outside of the jQuery `$(document).ready(function());`

Comment: No it doesn't work at all then :(

Comment: you need to put it inside the raphael document.onload function. Go to the Raphael documentation on the site, and its the first thing

Comment: Haha YES. Put that into an answer and I'll mark it as the correct answer. My problem was that I needed to put `Raphael(function() {` as the initiator for the javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the Raphael Initiator Function around the raphael code to make it work. Eg.
`raphael(function(){`