# Raphael JS, IE9 problems

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, raphael

I have written a simple game in Raphael JS, this works in all other browsers except IE9. On IE9 it just break apart like even the functions which are getting called in other browsers don't get called here. I feel something basic is going wrong. Could someone please help me on this ....

Link to the game: http://www.onlinegamesbuzz.com/demo/shaheen/egypt/hangman/hangman.v1.html

-Thanks

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8769446/raphael-js-not-rendering-correctly-in-ie9-document-mode) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8304299/ie-9-is-not-rendering-images-with-raphael-js-library)

Comment: Thanks Adnan, I tried setting these meta headers but somehow none of them worked for me :(

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />

And this workaround I did not understand, do you know how to use it ? 
You need to put the Raphael Initiator Function around the raphael code to make it work. Eg. raphael(function(){ 

-Thanks